# On Reddit's API: How can I get top posts of a certain time period as json?

Tags: json, api, time, parameters, reddit

How do I get, for example, a json containing all (as long as all < 100) posts from /r/tifu between Jan 1, 2016 and July 31, 2016?

I've been looking around the documentation, stackoverflow, and /r/redditdev, but I had no luck finding this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

All of reddit's listings are pre-computed, and there are none pre-computed that match those specific requirements.

You *may* be able to get what you want by [adding a timestamp range to the advanced search syntax](https://www.reddit.com/wiki/search#wiki_cloudsearch_syntax).  This will not be sorted by score, and may or may not continue to work, as it's not officially exposed as an API.